# Ruby on Rails on Windows - IIS 7 or IIS 6?

Tags: windows, iis, ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I have seen a few places ( [one example](http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2008/08/02/Leverage-the-Top-10-Performance-Improvements-in-IIS-7.0-.aspx) ) that there are newer speed improvements in IIS 7 on Windows 2008. While I know we would see possibly more power running ruby on rails under a Linux machine, the requirements depend on me using Windows.

I was wondering if anyone knew the best setup for Ruby/Rails in a Windows environment. This machine will mainly be running a redmine.org instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend running RoR on Windows for production, ruby has performances issues on Windows, and a lot of gems will not work....

Take a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164896/limitations-in-running-ruby-rails-on-windows

Comment: I usually wouldn't run it on Windows for so many different reasons, but this was part of the requirements due to some other software. Thank you for your link.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a little late, but consider using [Helicon Zoo](http://www.helicontech.com/zoo/) to run Ruby on Rails onder IIS 7 and IIS 7.5

Answer (score 0):

[Instant Rails](http://instantrails.rubyforge.org/wiki/wiki.pl) is what I used in my 3 hours of windows-based rails development.  Note that IIS would only be used for SOME of the serving, not all of it, I think.

Comment: Do you have a link talking about the 'IIS only being used for some serving'?

Thanks for the link, I already was using something like this, but called Bitnami.